# Rails 3 - How to Dynamically Duplicate Record and Submit Multiple Records on Single Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an INVOICE form.  To eliminate tons of typing, users need to enter invoice attributes, then click a button to copy the first record, change a couple attributes, then save all the records at once.  Excel style.  Help?

```
<% form_for @invoice, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_messages %>


<table class="ExcelTable2007">
     <tr>      
       <th class="heading">PO #<font color="red"> *</font></th>
       <th class="heading">Invoice #</th>
       <th class="heading">"Bill To" is Correct</th>
       <th class="heading">Invoice Date</th>
       <th class="heading">Date Received</th>
       <th class="heading">AP Clerk Note</th>
       <th class="heading">Division</th>
       <th class="heading">GR Approver</th>
       <th class="heading">GR Alternate Approver</th>
       <th class="heading">Invoice Attachment</th>
     </tr>  
     <tr>      
       <td class="heading"><%= f.text_field :po_number, :size => 10 %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.text_field :invoice_number, :size => 10 %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.check_box :bill_to_address %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.calendar_date_select "invoice_date", :time => false, :size => 12 %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.calendar_date_select "date_received", :time => false, :size => 12 %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.text_field :clerk_note %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.collection_select :division_id, Division.active.order(:division), :id, :division, :include_blank => true %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.collection_select :approver_username, Aduser.order(:last_name, :first_name), :username, :fullname, :include_blank => true %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.collection_select :alternate_approver_username, Aduser.order(:last_name, :first_name), :username, :fullname, :include_blank => true %></td>
       <td class="heading"><%= f.file_field :attachment %></td>
      </tr>
    </p>
</table>
&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<%= link_to "Add Invoice", clone_invoice_url(@invoice) %>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I tried the following, but receive an invalid authenticity token:

```
def clone_invoice
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id]).dup
  @invoice.save
end
```

Can anyone help me?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
def clone_invoice
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @new_invoice = @invoice.dup
end
```

If your invoice has an attachment then you would also want to copy that.

```
dupfile(@invoice.attachement.to_s, @new_invoice.attachment.to_s)
```

In your routes file, try

```
match 'invoices/:id/invoice_clone' => "invoices#clone_invoice", :as => "invoice_clone"
```

Then in your `link_to`, change the `clone_invoice_url` to `invoice_clone_path`

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I tried that, but get "Couldn't find Invoice without an ID"

Comment: what does your routes file look like for clone_invoice

Comment: match 'clone_invoice' => 'invoices#clone_invoice'   Since the first record isn't saved first, isn't that why the clone doesn't work?  They need to create multiple records at the same time, but use the first one they put in as the template before it is saved...

Comment: ah, i was assuming that you had the invoice record already created.

Comment: If you're looking to clone a form and it's data to another form below that information similar to a copy and paste in excel with rows then you would need to do some ajax. When you click the clone link, the javascript/jquery would append below the form data and values.

Comment: yeah, sorry I wasn't clear.  So, that's what I need help with, then.  I'm not js savvy, I'm afraid...